# SpiderMonkey REST request

Tags: javascript, v8, rhino, spidermonkey, javascriptcore

I'm trying to use Mozilla SpiderMonkey to parse JSON files, and I can easily read JSON from a local file on my Linux using read(). Is there a way that I can read JSON files directly from a website?  such as http://someDomain.com/myData.json

If not, does any of the other JavaScript engines have the ability to perform direct REST requests?

I'm using SpiderMonkey on CentOS 6.x and using it via JS Shell.

Comment: What is your environment? Do you use the SpiderMonkey shell? Is it a requirement to use the JS shell?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @timaschew, I updated my original post with the specs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: with SpiderMonkey you can parse JavaScript code to an AST (abstract syntax tree)

To parse a JSON you don't need SpiderMonkey. Or do you also some other operations?

And you cannot do XHR things with SpiderMonkey:

from https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_User_Guide

> The word JavaScript may bring to mind features such as event handlers (like onclick), DOM objects, window.open, and XMLHttpRequest. But in Mozilla, all of these features are actually provided by other components, not the SpiderMonkey engine itself.

If you wanna do it with SpiderMonkey you need to wrap it into another environment (maybe [envjs](http://www.envjs.com/)) that gives you XHR features.

Why you don't use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) with [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) which is a library for Node.js for REST things.
Then you only need parse the response of the JSON file: `var obj = JSON.parse(response)`